# Test of put users in a table html with capybara and expect an xpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, factory-bot

I have a user table in my view ruby on rails 5.1, and it's like this:

```
<table id="users" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellidos</th>
      <th>Correo electrónico</th>
      <th colspan="2">Registro</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td>i</td>
        <td><%= user.id %></td>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= user.created_at.hour %>:<%= user.created_at.min%> hrs.</td>
        <td><%= user.created_at.to_date %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The situation is that I'm working in testing with capybara, rspec & factorybot and I need to test that I'm creating 10 users and adding it to the table, after that i will expect an xpath for my test that is the one below:

```
 scenario 'admin view users' do
    visit admin_users_path
    users = create_list(:user, 10)
    expect(page).to have_xpath('//*[@id="users"]/tbody/tr/td[5]', text: "#{users.first.email}" )
  end
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error for the **expect**, and my hypothesis is that the xpath is correct, but there is something that cannot write or test the users inside the table.

**My question is:**

How can i run a test when I'm creating 10 users (for example) and then add it to the table for afterwords expect the xpath correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution:**

Apparently, I was creating the users after visit the page, so the view never receive the data. I was able to resolve it by change the order of the creation of users and after that visit the page and then I can expect the xpath correctly.

```
scenario 'admin view users' do
   users = create_list(:user, 10)
   visit admin_users_path
   expect(page).to have_xpath('//*[@id="users"]/tbody/tr/td[5]', text: "#{users.first.email}" )
end
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using XPath for this?  People on stackoverflow have often read old tutorials that show XPath and they just keep doing it, but nowadays you're going to be much better off using CSS when possible. In this case `expect(page).to have_css('#users tbody td:nth-child(5)' text: users.first.email)`.  CSS is faster, easier to read, much better with classes and doesn't escape scope by default (by starting your XPath with // rather than .// you will have  issues if you ever scope the query - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap )

Comment: I had read that many people use the `have_css` tag in the past, but I didn't understand why until know! thanks so much for the observation! I will look up for that! @ThomasWalpole